# Format JSON object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs

I have a JSON object which keys and values are in different format. I want to format it in right JSON format. PFB JSON data

I want to convert below json

```
  {
              \"abc\": \"test\",
              \"xyz\": \"test1\",
              \"array\": [
                  {
                      \"path\": [\"test\"],
                      \"output\": {}
                  }
              ]
    }
```

To format like below

```
 {
            "abc": "test",
            "xyz": "test1",
            "array": [
                {
                    "path": ["test"],
                    "output": {}
                }
            ]
   }
```

I get this JSON from Database which I need to convert to valid JSON.

I am not getting an idea how to format this JSON. Is there any regex that will format entire JSON object?

Comment: @Jite how often do you talk about JSON booleans or JSON numbers? There are pretty much two common "compount JSON" words - a JSON string which is actually just JSON (since it's already a string) and a JSON object which is what people mistakenly use to refer to either JSON or JavaScript objects. If you insist that a "JSON object" is the correct way to refer to a member of JSON that is an object, then you're the first person I've seen who does that. When people talk *about JSON* they already know what an object is a member and don't generally think Java or Smalltalk. A qualifier is useless.

Comment: @vlaz, I would probably include the word json if there was no earlier context. If I was already talking about JSON, I'd likely use the data type only though. I'm not saying that it's the best way to refer to the data type as JSON Object, but I'm saying that it's a valid way to say it and it can be a good idea to say it in a case like this due to it else having no obvious context.

Comment: As per some of your other posts, your questions have a pleading tone that is not appropriate for technical writing. Please make an effort not to add begging or chatty material - Stack Overflow is not a chatroom.

Comment: @halfer Sorry I didn't get the context

Comment: OK, no problem. There is a desire amongst content contributors on Stack Overflow to aim for technical writing, so that posts are as readable as possible for future readers. [This post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions) is probably the canonical reference. Thus, we (and I) ask that you keep chatty material out of your posts. For example, [this edit and rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51494712/revisions) on one of your prior questions.

Comment: I sometimes give the following advice, which would apply to a number of items in your post history: _Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened._

Comment: @halfer Thanks for your time. I agree with your inputs., I will follow the same going forward

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var data = `{
              \"abc\": \"test\",
              \"xyz\": \"test1\",
              \"array\": [
                  {
                      \"path\": [\"test\"],
                      \"output\": {}
                  }
              ]
            }`;

console.log(JSON.parse(data));
```

Comment: Thank you this is working fine after I do JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(data)); Template literals does the magic

Answer (score 1):

If you get this data as string - just do:

`JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(data))`

Answer is just for case, when you have string with escaped `"`, If there are some other symbols, `JSON.parse` may throw Error.

Comment: This is exactly what happened but parse worked after putting JSON in template literalsliterals

Answer (score 1):

Actually `JSON.parse` would be enough for that string

Answer (score 1):

```
const data = '{\"abc\": \"test\",\"xyz\": \"test1\",\"array\":[{ \"path\":[\"test\"],\"output\":{}}]}';


var jsondata = JSON.parse(data);
console.log('jsondata: ', jsondata);

var regex = data.replace(/\\/g, '');
console.log('regex: ', regex);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use this regexp: `\\"` and replace captured result by `"`. If variable `data` has not-valid json you can use following code:

```
data.replace(/\\"/g,'"');
```

Here is regexp example: https://regex101.com/r/qUV7St/1

Comment: @Think-Twice JSON.parse(data) will not work for not-valid json - as example try this: `var data = '{ \\"abc\\": \\"test\\"}'` (this wil produce in `data` following string: `'{ \"abc\": \"test\"}'`)- for this string you will get exception on parse. So if your Database return not-valid string you need to fix it before parse.